# Where do I find cordova.js?

Tags: javascript, cordova, include

I'm writing a mobile app with **HTML5**, **Javascript** and **CSS3**. 
I'm using phonegap.

So if I use something like this.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
    alert("test");
}
```

I get this error:

> cordova : You must have cordova.js included in your projects, to be able to trigger events.

I'm using **Ripple** to emulate a smartphone. And its right. I don't have `cordova.js` in my project folder, because I don't know where i get it. 
I have downloaded the newest version 2.9.0 of **phonegap** and using specially cordova-mobile-spec.

There is no `cordova.js` just a `cordova-incl.js`. How do I obtain this file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the `cordova.js` inside the new project created (by using command line)

OR

CHECK YOUR LIB FOLDE INSIDE THE DOWNLOADED CORDOVA ZIP FILE

[image]

[image]

FOR **IOS** CHECK  **cordovalib** folder

[image]

[image]

**ANDROID**

[image]

Please check libs folder of each platform.

Answer (score 62):

I wasted a lot of time looking for a solution on the question "Where get the cordova.js?".
I am developing a mobile app using html+css+jQuery mobile and i am building it using the  [phonegap web build service](https://build.phonegap.com/). The version of phonegap i am working on is 3.1.0.

I was trying to find how to use the [Phonegap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/index.html) on my mobile application and how to call the cordova methods (ex notification.alert). The solution to this is to just add the

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

inside the head of your index.html document. The Phonegap builder will find and include the correct cordova.js file for each build (Android, Win phone, iOS).

Finally, the [ondeviceready event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) is essential to any application. See the Full Example.

Comment: When using Ripple, browser, etc to test code, make sure you are using the compiled code, not the root directory.  So use the files under `%ROOT_DIR%\platforms\<your_platform>` instead.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19247356/1212045) as well.

Comment: The important thing for me was putting the <script src="cordova.js"></script> in the head area of the index.html.  Mine was down in the body and failing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I also wasted a lot of time trying to figure out what was going on here, because not even George's solution was working for me.

Finally I realized that, as my *index.html* page is not in the root of the *www* folder, but inside a subdirectory of it, I should be then setting a relative path for the cordova file (i.e. `src="../cordova.js"`).

Hope it helps anyone else having the same [dumb] issue.

Comment: Your index.html should be in the ROOT! But I guess you've done something different.

Comment: thanks. I am using vue/webpack, and it structures things a little differently than the default cordova setup, I suspect this is why the source is found one level up

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run on your browser for testing, it is suggested to build for browser and run from there, because every time you build the right cordova.js file is included according to the platform.

To build for browser:

> cordova build browser

To run:

> cordova run browser

More options

> cordova run browser -- --port=8001 --target=Firefox

To run with plugins here is a quick intro guide https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/03/22/the-cordova-browser-platform