# Error while accessing cordova.js - "Cordova_Not_Available" (ionic 2)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm to trying to take a picture using native Camera module (works fine on android device), but while running the same on web viewer got the following error (chrome console)

```
plugin.js:33 Native: tried calling Camera.getPicture, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
cordovaWarn @ plugin.js:33
callCordovaPlugin @ plugin.js:112
(anonymous) @ plugin.js:159
(anonymous) @ plugin.js:131
t @ polyfills.js:3
tryNativePromise @ plugin.js:130
getPromise @ plugin.js:152
wrapPromise @ plugin.js:158
(anonymous) @ plugin.js:325
value @ plugin.js:386
TabsPage.takePhoto @ tabs.ts:36
TabsPage.shootMessage @ tabs.ts:29
View_TabsPage0.handleEvent_5 @ component.ngfactory.js:124
(anonymous) @ view.js:408
schedulerFn @ async.js:94
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
Tabs.select @ tabs.js:327
View_Tabs1.handleEvent_0 @ component.ngfactory.js:212
(anonymous) @ view.js:408
schedulerFn @ async.js:94
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
TabButton.onClick @ tab-button.js:30
Wrapper_TabButton.handleEvent @ wrapper.ngfactory.js:99
View_Tabs1.handleEvent_0 @ component.ngfactory.js:210
(anonymous) @ view.js:408
(anonymous) @ dom_renderer.js:276
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:227
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
**tabs.ts:45 cordova_not_available**
```

Already tried

- [ionic 2 error cordova not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744657/ionic-2-error-cordova-not-available)
- https://medium.com/@barsh/loading-cordova-js-from-a-website-27966844ba56#.9d23v9yd0
- [Where get the cordova.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651496/where-get-the-cordova-js)

I can also see the file is present in the folder at multiple places but somehow it is not getting accessed.

[image]

ionic info

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: Is cordova.js available in your index.html?

Comment: not sure what the web viewer is but camera is a native functionality, therefore it only works on a actual device. and also, cordova is 404 during development

Comment: cordova plugins are not supported for `ionic serve` they work only in emulator/actual device