# `cordova.exec` not working in capacitor project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, azure-ad-msal, capacitor

I'm trying to integrate my `Ionic/Capacitor` app with Microsoft Authentication Library (Msal), and unfortunately I couldn't found any Capacitor plugin for that, only found this [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/wrobins/cordova-plugin-msal) with its [Ionic wrapper](https://binaryops.ca/blog/implementing-msal-authentication-ionic).

So I've followed the instructions of [how to use Cordova plugins with capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/cordova/using-cordova-plugins) according with the instructions of the plugin itself, but unfortunately with no success.

The problem is in the cordova plugin not being executed:

`cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'MsalPlugin', 'msalInit', [JSON.stringify(options)]);`

because `cordova.js` is not exist. Although I added the `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugin.js` in `index.html`, but still the `cordova.js` file is empty when use `chrome://inspect`.

Also `cordova.js` is exist in `android\app\src\main\assets` but it seems like it's an old version that is not containing the method `androidExec()` which is being called when try on another `Ionic/Cordova` app. But even this version not exist when run application on emulator.

The msal Cordova plugin added with commands:
`npm i --save cordova-plugin-msal`
and
`npm i --save ionic-msal-native`

**Platforms**
Android

**package.json dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.1.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.1.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-msal": "^2.5.0",
    "ionic-msal-native": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

**Capacitor Doctor**

```
Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 3.1.2
  @capacitor/core: 3.1.2
  @capacitor/android: 3.1.2
  @capacitor/ios: 3.1.2

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/ios: not installed
  @capacitor/core: 3.1.2
  @capacitor/cli: 3.1.2
  @capacitor/android: 3.1.2

[success] Android looking great!
```

`npm --version`: 6.14.14
`node --version`: v14.17.4

was i missing something or made something wrong?

Comment: I tried to add the `cordova.js` file inside `www` folder manually, then run the synch command `npx cap synch android`, but still got nothing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are testing your app in the browser? Generally cordova plugins don't work/get loaded in the browser as they are meant to bridge the gap between native functionality and your javascript based frontend. Best would be to run your code in an emulator or on a real device to see your plugin in action.

You might also find some answers here
[Where do I find cordova.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651496/where-do-i-find-cordova-js)

Comment: No i'm not testing on browser, i'm just using the browser for inspecting, i'm testing on android AVD with android studio.